# Paste with middle button emulation does not work

Tags: xorg, mouse, clipboard, wayland

Suddenly after trying wayland and switching back to Xorg, middle button emulation stops of working.

Below my system information:

```
 OS: Fedora 25 TwentyFive
 Kernel: x86_64 Linux 4.10.8-200.fc25.x86_64
 Shell: bash
 DE: KDE 5.33.0 / Plasma 5.8.6
 WM: KWin
 WM Theme: Aurorae
```

libinput shows this about touchpad as follows:

Device:           SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad
Kernel:           /dev/input/event6
Group:            7
Seat:             seat0, default
Size:             98.04x48.03mm
Capabilities:     pointer 
Tap-to-click:     disabled
Tap-and-drag:     enabled
Tap drag lock:    disabled
Left-handed:      disabled
Nat.scrolling:    disabled
Middle emulation: n/a
Calibration:      n/a
Scroll methods:   *two-finger edge 
Click methods:    none
Disable-w-typing: enabled
Accel profiles:   none
Rotation:         n/a

xinput says:

```
xinput list-props 12
Device 'SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad':
        Device Enabled (115):   1
        Coordinate Transformation Matrix (117): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
        libinput Tapping Enabled (252): 0
        libinput Tapping Enabled Default (253): 0
        libinput Tapping Drag Enabled (254):    1
        libinput Tapping Drag Enabled Default (255):    1
        libinput Tapping Drag Lock Enabled (256):       0
        libinput Tapping Drag Lock Enabled Default (257):       0
        libinput Tapping Button Mapping Enabled (258):  1, 0
        libinput Tapping Button Mapping Default (259):  1, 0
        libinput Accel Speed (260):     0.000000
        libinput Accel Speed Default (261):     0.000000
        libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled (262):       0
        libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled Default (263):       0
        libinput Send Events Modes Available (237):     1, 1
        libinput Send Events Mode Enabled (238):        0, 0
        libinput Send Events Mode Enabled Default (239):        0, 0
        libinput Left Handed Enabled (264):     0
        libinput Left Handed Enabled Default (265):     0
        libinput Scroll Methods Available (266):        1, 1, 0
        libinput Scroll Method Enabled (267):   1, 0, 0
        libinput Scroll Method Enabled Default (268):   1, 0, 0
        libinput Disable While Typing Enabled (269):    1
        libinput Disable While Typing Enabled Default (270):    1
        Device Node (240):      "/dev/input/event6"
        Device Product ID (241):        2, 7
        libinput Drag Lock Buttons (271):       <no items>
        libinput Horizontal Scroll Enabled (272):       1
```

I can't set it by hand:

```
xinput set-prop  '12' 'libinput Middle Emulation Enabled' 1
property 'libinput Middle Emulation Enabled' doesn't exist, you need to specify its type and format
```

Is there a conflict between Wayland and Xorg? How can I reset the middle button emulation of mousepad?

**UPDATE**

I've found libinput-debug-events outputs:

```
-event6   POINTER_BUTTON    +2.50s      BTN_MIDDLE (274) pressed, seat count: 1
 event6   POINTER_BUTTON    +2.72s      BTN_MIDDLE (274) released, seat count: 0
```

So it's matter of paste problem (in fact, text is copied in klipper), any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I've found the reason. I've created a `Mouse Gesture Action` in Plasma System Setting, and if I choose button 2 paste with emulated middle button does not work.

Changing button to 3 fixes the problem.